# WPF bug? Grid's column does not accommodate ListBox scrollbar

Tags: wpf, grid, resize

In the following example, the leftmost column's width does not increase to accommodate the `ListBox`'s scrollbar that appears when the `UserControl`'s height is decreased:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="Example">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Example text</TextBlock>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Four</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Five</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <Expander Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Header="Expander" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When the `TextBlock` with the `ColumnSpan` attribute is removed the column resizes as expected. Is this a bug in WPF?

Comment: I can recreate this behavior in Kaxaml, and it doesn't appear to matter in what order you declare things. Perhaps you could submit a bug to connect.microsoft.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is [a known bug with the ListBox scrollbar and the WPF Grid](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362223). Microsoft also notes they will probably not have this fixed in 4.0.

Comment: The search function at connect.microsoft.com would not find this bug, funny enough Google found it for me without much trouble.