# ScrollViewer in ItemsControl - ScrollBar not shown but working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

This is not your average "My ScrollViewer isn't working" question...
Assume a window with a grid. The sizes of column 0 and row 1 are set to `Auto`, column 1 and row 0 are set to `*`. (important)
In cell [0, 0] there is an `ItemsControl` with a Template with a `StackPanel` inside a `ScrollViewer` inside a `Grid`. The reason is simple: Show a scroll bar if not all items in the `ItemsControl` can be displayed. The visibility of the vertical scrollbar is set to `Auto` (important).
In Cell [1, 1] there is a `Button` that displays its width.

If the window is too small too display all items in the `ItemsControl` this will lead to the following:
The scroll bar will be there but it is not visible. It is working, because I can scroll using the mouse wheel. The reason seems to be that the grid column in which the `ItemsControl` is contained is not automatically extended to make space for the scrollbar.

If I change (nearly) *any* of the parameters, the scroll bar is displayed as expected and the second column is reduced in size. **Can anyone explain this odd behavior?**

---

**Additional Info:**

The following parameter changes will lead to the scrollbar becoming visible:

1. Changing size of column 0 to `*`
2. Changing size of column 1 to `Auto`
3. Changing size of row 1 to `*`
4. Removing the `Button`.
5. Moving the `Button` to [0, 1] or [1, 0]
6. Manually setting the width of the `ItemsControl`.
7. Setting the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` of the `ScrollViewer` in the `ItemsControl` to `Visible`.

However, changing the button in [1, 1] to something else, e.g. another `ItemsControl` doesn't change the strange behavior, so it has nothing to with the button. Furthermore, changing the width of the `Button` to something that is smaller than the second column, also doesn't remove that behavior.

---

**Complete sample code for reproduction:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="343" Width="253">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl>
      <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
              <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ScrollViewer>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.Template>
      <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Button Content="Column1" Height="500" />
      </ItemsControl.Items>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Content="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it might be a known bug in WPF. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313341/wpf-bug-grids-column-does-not-accommodate-listbox-scrollbar/1313480#1313480) deals with a ListBox's ScrollViewer, but I think the principal is the same.

As an alternative, you could add something behind the ScrollViewer that has it's width bound to the ScrollViewer's ActualWidth, which will force the column to draw the correct size

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="Test" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Button Content="Column1" Height="500" />
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
          Width="{Binding ElementName=Test, Path=ActualWidth}" />

    <Button Content="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you test this? It doesn't change anything. Furthermore, this introduces the problem that virtualisation doesn't work anymore, because the ItemsControl always has its full size.

Comment: I'm sorry, no I didn't. I thought the scrollviewer wasn't having it's height limited

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I changed my answer. +1 to the question for being interesting though. I've never encountered this issue before but it seems to be easy to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Good idea with the dummy element. There is just one more problem with it: The scrollbar still isn't shown, if the user hasn't resized the window since the program has been started and the program started in a size that would need the scrollbar right from the start, although the label has the correct size. However, this seems to be happening only in my original sample with the ItemsControl, not with your simplified one.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Strange, that code is copy/pasted from VS and works fine for me. It also works with the ItemsControl code you posted, providing I bind to the `ItemsControl.ActualWidth` instead of the templated `ScrollViewer.ActualWidth`

Comment: Yes, but not if that dummy element is inside the `ItemsControl` template.

Comment: BTW: Binding the grid column width to the `ItemsControl` also works - without the need for a dummy element.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The problem seems to occur when a `ScrollBar` of any kind is displayed in a `Grid.Column` where the `Width="Auto"`, and there is at least one other column where `Width="*"` (all remaining space). This matches your outer grid, and not the inner grid, so put the dummy element inside your outer grid.